# How do you steer the screw attack in Metroid Prime 3: Corruption?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

When I received the screw attack in *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption*, I was told that I could steer while using it by using [image: The Icon], which *appeared* to be the analog stick on the nunchuck.

But try as I might, no matter what direction on the nunchuck's analog stick I press, I always go straight while using the screw attack...

How do you steer the screw attack in Metroid Prime 3: Corruption?

*EDIT:* Here's a full screen capture:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to post some screen captures to demonstrate this, but I discovered that you *can* steer the screw attack using the control stick. It's just that you can only steer about 5° or 10° in either direction. Starting in a large, open room I jumped, space jumped, and then started to screw-attack and held right on the nunchuck's analog stick, and jumped as far as I could. I then repeated this holding left on the analog stick as well as not touching the analog stick at all. The difference was very slight, but there was a difference.

**EDIT:** Here's some screen captures:

I tried three tests, starting from here each time:
[image: Starting Position]

If I use the screw attack all five times and don't hold any direction, I end up here:
[image: Straight Ahead]

Using the screw attack and holding left, I hit the pillar before I can jump all 7 times:
[image: Slightly left]

If I hold right on the analog stick when using the screw attack, I do go right. Check the map:
[image: To the right]

So **the difference is very slight**, maybe 5° or 10° in either direction. But there *is* a difference...

Answer (score 0):

You can not decisively steer the screw attack. Like in Metroid Prime Two, the Screw Attack is used for clearing long horizontal distances, and climbing up the screw jump walls.

Though it's been a while since I played the game, I imagine the item-tutorial tips were referring to this latter ability.

Comment: I'm so tempted to accept this answer since it's how I feel, LOL. I'll probably post a screen capture, because I don't think they were referring to the screw jump walls. I can climb those without using the control stick at all, the game automatically reverses my direction for me...

Comment: A picture would help diagnose, for sure.

Comment: I did some tests and will post some screen shots soon...

Comment: I posted screen captures, both of the instructions, as well as my test proving that the steering does work, it just barely has any effect at all...